# How to Delete a list of tuple recursively based on parameter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function that takes 2 parameters, the second parament takes a list of tuples. The pair of tuples gets deleted if first component is equal to the first parameter.

**eg myDelete 2 [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, ’c’)] = [(1, 'a'), (3, ’c’)]**

Here is what I have tried

```
myDelete :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
myDelete a [] = []
myDelete a ((l, r) :xs) | a==l      = myDelete a xs
                          | otherwise = l: r:(myDelete a xs)
```

Comment: you're very close, the only thing that's wrong (as the compiler will tell you) is the last line, where you have `l:r`. What do you think you should have there instead?

Comment: PS you could write this function more elegantly using the `filter` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `l : r : …` part. You return a list of 2-tuples. `l` has type `a`, and `r` has type `b`, so you prepend the list with expressions of type `a` and `b`, but that will not work.

You should prepend the list with the 2-tuple `(l, r)`:

```
myDelete :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
myDelete a [] = []
myDelete a ((l, r) :xs)
    | a == l = myDelete a xs
    | otherwise = (l, r): myDelete a xs
```

You can also make use of an [*as-pattern* [Haskell report]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.17.1) to avoid wrapping `l` and `r` in a 2-tuple:

```
myDelete :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
myDelete a [] = []
myDelete a (lr@(l, _) :xs)
    | a == l = myDelete a xs
    | otherwise = lr: myDelete a xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Something you could try is this.

```hs
myDelete a = filter ((/=a) . fst)
```

It means you would map `(/=a)` over the first parameter.